# Ionic 7 React not working on Android 8 but on Android 11

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am developing an app that should be used on a ActivePanel (Smartboard). This panel has Android 8 installed.

When I start the newly created Ionic 7 project on a virtual device with Android 11, everything runs smoothly. However, when I start it on the same virtual device with Android 8, the app starts but doesn't show any texts, components, etc. and only appears as a white screen.

Log:

[https://pastebin.com/kq6xgJbD](https://stackoverflow.com)

Logcat:

[https://pastebin.com/uy2rH8BH](https://stackoverflow.com)

I assume the problem is related to EGL and rendering?

Do you have any suggestions on how I can make the app start on Android 8?

I tried to run the app on different Virtual Devices, but it never works on an Android 8 device...

Comment: Please post code here and not via links.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Links are not working for me. In any case, it looks like the app is executing JavaScript that is not understood by the webview's browser. Try to connect your desktop chrome dev tools to the android emulator or device and check the JavaScript console for errors.